# IBM Watson translator Post request, failed with Response 400

Tags: java, api, ibm-watson

I am trying to use IBM translator through API, it totally works with Postman with the following info:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYhkp.png)

and also I added user pass like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GegN.png)

Now I try to write the code for the same request in java but it does not work and always failed, I was reading all other question and answered and did the same but still not working!
here is my code:

```
 private static void PostRequest() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://api.eu-gb.language-translator.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/405430e3-281c-4c40-8d64-139173d288c3/v3/translate?version=2018-05-01");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    String username = "apikey";
    String password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    String authString = username + ":" + password;
    System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
    byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
    String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
    System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

    

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    //create a request Body
    String jsonBody = "{\"text\": [\"Hello, world.\", \"How are you?\"], \"model_id\":\"en-ar\"}";
    //write it
    try(OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {
        byte[] input = jsonBody.getBytes("utf-8");
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }

    //Read the response
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String responseLine = null;
        while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(responseLine.trim());
        }
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
```

could anybody please let me know how should I add my authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working more and found the answer, I had to write the following code:

```
private static void PostRequest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  // Customer ID
    final String customerKey = username;
    // Customer secret
    final String customerSecret = password;

    // Concatenate customer key and customer secret and use base64 to encode the concatenated string
    String plainCredentials = customerKey + ":" + customerSecret;
    String base64Credentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredentials.getBytes()));
    // Create authorization header
    String authorizationHeader = "Basic " + base64Credentials;

    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

    // Create HTTP request object
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(url1))
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString( "{\"text\": [\"Hello, world.\", \"How are you?\"], \"model_id\":\"en-ar\"}"))
            .header("Authorization", authorizationHeader)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build();
    // Send HTTP request
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
            HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

    System.out.println(response.body());
}
```

and the response was :

```
{
```

"translations" : [ {
"translation" : "مرحبا أيها العالم"
}, {
"translation" : "كيف حالك ؟"
} ],
"word_count" : 8,
"character_count" : 25
}